# should tag [mechanicalengeneering] be renamed?

Tags: discussion, tags

All tags involving 2 words are spelled with an dash between both words (e.g. [aviation-history](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aviation-history)). The tag [mechanicalengineering](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanicalengineering) does not follow this convention. Should we rename it? if so, how? (I fail to create the tag with a dash because it is too close to the other one)

Comment: Side note, to include tags in posts you can use the syntax `[tag:the-tag-name]` no need to link them directly.

Answer (score 6):

I have un-tagged both questions which had that tag, it added nothing over the tags that were already present and I agree it was named incorrectly.

Now no questions are tagged it shall hopefully die out. If it doesn't I'd suggest it is just a synonym of [engineering](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engineering)